# Java RTF import, edit and export possible?

Tags: java, parsing, export, rtf, apache-tika

I use Apache Tika to parse RTF files to get the plaintext as string. Now I want to remove some characters from this string -> ok. Now I want to save the result as RTF again. (You can think of this process as modifying an RTF file by deleting a paragraph.) How is this possible? How can I export this string to RTF with Tika?

Comment: Why not use a proper RTF library to edit directly, rather than trying to turn it into plain text then back again?

Comment: i have to search for certain keywords and paragraphs in this rtf and remove them. Can you name a proper RTF library for Java?

Comment: I tried with the standard Java Swing RTFEditorKit. It WOULD work fine if the RTFEditorKit would support multilanguage RTFs... unfortunately it doesn't (i need to go multilanguage!). Parsing Chinese and russian rtfs results in garbage, because the RTFEditorKit does not supply per-font encoding! I found this little comment in RTFReader: /* TODO: per-font font encodings ( \fcharset control word ) ? */ -> This is what i needed...

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution to edit docs, but it is a little complex. You can use the OpenOffice API to open a lot of types of docs and export it to other formats. I used it, sometime ago, to read data from a database and export as an odt and xls file.

I never used it to [edit a doc](http://www.openoffice.org/udk/common/man/tutorial/office_automation.html), like a file from Writer or MS Word, but, by the [OpenOffice documentation](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Text/Text_Documents), I know that is possible to do it. Maybe this can be a cannon to kill a fly, but if you don find any other ways, could solve your problem.

The API works with Java, C++ etc.